# Exclude Protected methods in gradle javadoc build

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

I have written few utility classes with protected and public methods in it.  I want to exclude all the protected methods from javadocs when generated from Gradle.

in eclipse, we can do it by passing '-protected' parameter but it does not work in Gradle.

please let me know how can i do it in Gradle.

Answer (score 4):

Place the following snippet into your build.gradle file:

```
javadoc {
  options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
}
```